# Pandas: Order Rows in Datarame

Tags: python, pandas

Seeking the correct way to order my `sales` column so that the ranges represented are smallest to largest.

I've been using `pandas.df.sort_values(by='sales')` but the output isn't sequential.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Current DF: DF1

```
     sales           team    
0    950 to 1000     J
1    10 to 20        K
2    4000 to 5000    L
3    60 to 100       M
4    0 to 9          N
```

Desired DF: DF2

```
     sales           team    
0    0 to 9          N
1    10 to 20        K   
2    60 to 100       M      
3    950 to 1000     J
4    4000 to 5000    L
```

Comment: not really an answer so a comment will suffice - but with data like that you should create a mapping to integers,, which for this case has a sort order behaviour so map accordingly. you never want to do string matching especially with pandas dataframes!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this (extract the first number from the sales column and sort by it):

```
df.loc[df.sales.str.split(" ").str[0].astype(int).argsort()]

#   sales        team
#4  0 to 9          N
#1  10 to 20        K
#3  60 to 100       M
#0  950 to 1000     J
#2  4000 to 5000    L
```

Or another option with `str.extract()`:

```
df.loc[df.sales.str.extract("^(\d+)").astype(int).argsort()]
```